# Calculating Mobius Function for large numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, mobius-function

Is there any known algorithm for calculating whether a large, squarefree $N$ has an odd or even number of prime factors? That is, whether $\mu(N)=1$ or $\mu(N)=-1$, where $\mu(N)$ is the Mobius Function ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_function#Proof_of_the_formula_for_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Proof_of_the_formula_for_)∑d|n_μ(d))/, **without having to factor $N$**, as it is large.

Comment: No ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks as always, reuns.